# How to remove SSL redirect in Orchard site using backend?

Tags: ssl, orchardcms

I was setting up my Orchard site to require SSL.  I obviously set it up wrong and cannot access the page to change any settings since it is redirecting incorrectly. The error message that I am getting from Firefox is

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

I am sorry that I can't tell you what my settings were that I put in, since I cannot access the page.
I am asking if there is a way that I can change the web.config, or a field in the database that will allow me to get back into the site to put the correct settings in.  Any ideas?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings are saved in the site settings dataset in the database. Connect to your database with SQL Server Management Studio or other tool. Find table `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord` and very first row > column `Data` should hold your Site settings with SSL entry, should look like

```
<SslSettingsPart>
    <Urls></Urls>
    <SecureEverything>False</SecureEverything>
    <Enabled>True</Enabled>
    <CustomEnabled>False</CustomEnabled>
    <SecureHostName>localhost:44302</SecureHostName>
    <InsecureHostName>localhost:10421</InsecureHostName>
</SslSettingsPart>
```

Tweak as necessary or delete this whole part and set it again through administration.

Make sure that after you make this database change you save it and restart your site or else it might not take effect.